# aiopg + sqlalchemy: how to "drop table if exists" without raw sql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, drop-table, aiopg

I am looking at [examples of aiopg usage with sqlalchemy](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#default-value-field-sqlalchemy-usage) and these lines scare me:

```
async def create_table(conn):
    await conn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl')
    await conn.execute(CreateTable(tbl))
```

I do not want to execute raw sql queries when using sqlalchemy. However I can't find any other way to implement the same logic. My attempts were:

1)

```
await conn.execute(tbl.drop(checkfirst=True))
```

This raises:

> sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Table object 'tbl' is not
>   bound to an Engine or Connection.  Execution can not proceed without a
>   database to execute against.

Also I can't find a way to bind the table to engine because [aiopg doesn't support metadata.create_all](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg/issues/123#issuecomment-232604788)

2)

```
await conn.execute(DropTable(tbl))
```

This raises:

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: table "tbl" does not exist

Seems like `DropTable` construct doesn't support `IF EXISTS` part in any way.

So, the question is, is there any way to rewrite `await conn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl')` statement into something without raw sql when using aiopg + sqlalchemy?

Comment: Normally `Table.drop()` accepts an optional  bind as the first positional argument, so you'd pass `conn` like `tbl.drop(conn, checkfirst=True)`, but I don't know if that's supported with async. There's btw. nothing wrong in executing actual SQL when working with SQLAlchemy, it even provides some helpers for doing that, such as `text()`.

Comment: What's wrong with catching `UndefinedTable`?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini it will be 4 rows (try, execute, except, pass) to execute this query, even worse than with raw sql. I am looking for the best (shortest, most pythonic) way to do it. I expect sqlalchemy to have built-in functionality for such simple queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This question was posted when the latest version was SQLAlchemy 1.3.11.*

As of SQLAlchemy 1.4.0, `DropTable` supports `if_exists=True`.

```py
await conn.execute(DropTable(tbl, if_exists=True))
```

Reference: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.DropTable